# flowtype inference fails based on file order

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In my source code, I have 3 folders sorted alphabetically. The first and third folders contain the exact same code. The second folder exports a typed function with generics. Strangely, only the third folder fails a flow check, folder one passes.

I would like for both files/folders to pass regardless of position in the source code.

Flow version: 0.98.1

[Link to github repo reproducing the issue](https://github.com/chasestarr/flow-reproduce-infer-error-position-in-source)

[Link to github issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7745)

some interesting notes:

- If the Options type is in the same file as fn calls, flow infers correctly.
- If the code is within the same folder, flow infers correctly.

[image: files-image]

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/c-after/index.js:6:24

string [1] is incompatible with number [2] in type argument N.

     src/c-after/index.js
     3│ import fn from "../b-function/index.js";
     4│ import type {Options} from "./types.js";
     5│
 [1] 6│ export const Comp = fn<Options>("hello", options => 2);
     7│

     src/b-function/index.js
 [2] 6│   <N: number, T>(N, (T) => number): any,



Found 1 error
```

Comment: Does Flow allow multiple call signatures for an object? I tried running the example with only one call signature and it seems to return the same result for both folders.

Comment: callable objects are documented here: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-callable-objects

Comment: Yeah, looks like there's a suggestion for only one call signature so I think you're probably running into an issue with having multiple call signatures. I'm guessing Flow doesn't want to handle function overrides since JS doesn't really support that.